# How to disable/customize real time error checking in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I work with vim, where I've made a keyboard mapping (CTRL + L) to begin error checking. Fact is real time error checking is as useful as annoying sometimes, so I'd like to know if there is a similar approach in Netbeans (I'm using version 7.2.1, coding in PHP).

Here's the desired behaviour:

- *Don't* check for errors automatically;
- Have some key mapping and/or menu action to *manually* check for errors.

Is it possible?

TIA,